# What is the appropriate Hibernate Jar for Spring 4.2.4?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have been trying to develop Spring MVC with Hibernate.

However I have been running into many issues. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate download link](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/)

You can download the latest hibernate version in the above link. You can use 5.0.6.Final. This is the latest version of hibernate. 
If you are new to spring and hibernate, please go through some basics tutorial in web. Following are some of the tutorial websites with examples through which you can understand well.

     [Hibernate and Spring Integration](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-and-spring-integration)


     [Spring and hibernate with registration example](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html) 

     [ORM with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

 Then start coding. Otherwise if you get any problem you will get stuck there. 
Thanks!